# Prefix on newlines in lstlisting environment

Tags: verbatim

I've defined my own lstlisting environment with `\lstnewenvironment`.
Now I'd like to prefix every new line of the code with arbitrary text (a bash cursor).

Basically I'd like this

```
\begin{commands}
Whatever
foo
\end{commands}
```

to give me this

```
#> Whatever
#> foo
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

**Please post a complete and compilable minimal [working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) with your next question.** This reduces the efforts of others to help you, and generally increases your chances to get an answer.

The following does what you have asked for. Inside the `commands` environment, we overwrite the `\thelstnumber` command, which `listings` uses internally to typeset the line number. The new version typesets the prefix instead:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{commands}[1][]{%
  \renewcommand{\thelstnumber}{\#>}
  \lstset{numbers=left,basicstyle=\ttfamily,#1}%
}{%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{commands}
Whatever
foo
\end{commands}

\end{document}
```

[image]